# MongoDB: $match with $or aggregation optimization

Tags: mongodb, optimization, match, aggregation

I faced an issue how optimize this  $match.
Currently I have this code

```
{ $match: {
            $or: [
                { 'card': { $eq: 'card1'},
                 $and: [
                         { 'createdAt': { $gte: three_months }},
                         { 'createdAt': { $lte: createdAt }}
                        ]
                },
                { 'client': { $eq: 'client1'},
                 $and: [
                         { 'client': { $ne: null }},
                         { 'createdAt': { $gte: three_months }},
                         { 'createdAt': { $lte: createdAt }}
                        ]
                },
            { 'destination_card': { $eq: 'destination_card1'},
                 $and: [
                         { 'createdAt': { $gte: three_months }},
                         { 'createdAt': { $lte: createdAt }}
                        ]
                },

            ]
           }
{ $limit: 300},
{ $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
```

But sometimes calculation is wrong or it executes too long.  Please could you give some idea how to optimize it somehow? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Use analyzer to check for bottlenecks https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a newer version of MongoDB (3.6+, I think), the query planner can use multiple indexes to handle the `$or`.  Each branch uses the same criteria on `createdAt`, so you could collect that together to list only once, like:

```
{$match: {
     {'createdAt':{$gte: three_months, $lte: createdAt}},
     {$or:[
        {'card': 'card1'},
        {'client': 'client1'},
        {'destination_card': 'destination_card1
     ]}
}}
```

If you create 3 indexes, each with one of the exact match fields and createdAt, like `{card:1, createdAt:1}` it will improve selection and reduce the number of documents examined, which may help execution time.

Note that using `$or` usually prevents the query executor from using the index to perform the sort, requiring an in-memory sort each time this query is run, which increases the RAM needed to execute this query, which may slow down the execution when the server is busy.

Comment: Dear Joe, thank you very much for your answer! It helped me a lot!